# How to rename files using a list of new names

Tags: list, file, rename

I need help to rename files in a directory using a list of new names, I have tryed some recommendation already posted here but they dont work .-(.
the pattern of the files is: 
    FRAGMSAUERGUERTH279_X_A01_015.fsa
until `X` it is a constant character and I'd like to change them for specific names that I have already upload in a file.
here is my script:

```
plate1<-(plate.1.anser) # new names in plate1    
dir1<-('D:/Doctorado/Anseriformes/Multiplex PCR anser/Micro geese 2015/fragmsauerguerth279/fragmsauerguerth279') # where my files are
filez<-list.files(dir1,pattern="*.fsa")
head(filez)     
apply(filez,FUN=function(eachPath){
  file.rename(from=eachPath,to=sub(pattern="*.fsa",replacement=plate1,eachPath))  #replacement=plate1[1,]:plate1[96,]    
})
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! What programming language is this supposed to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution .-):

```
 plate1<-as.vector(plate.1.anser)
 dir1<-("D://Doctorado//Anseriformes//Multiplex PCR anser//Micro geese 2015//fragmsauerguerth279//fragmsauerguerth279//")
 a <- list.files(dir1, pattern="*.fsa")  
 b <- paste(plate1[1:96,], ".fsa", sep = "") # 96 files in directory
 file.rename(from=file.path(dir1,a), to=file.path(dir1,b))
```